# Running time analysis of the loops

Tags: python, algorithm

Consider following loops:

```
def func1(xs, ys, zs):
    for x in xs:
        for y in ys:
            pass

        for z in zs:
            pass
```

The running time should take `size of xs * (size of ys + size of zs)`, which could be written in big-o notation as `O(X) * (O(Y) + O(Z))`.

```
def func2(xs, ys, zs):
    for y in ys:
        for x in xs:
            pass

    for z in zs:
        for x in xs:
            pass
```

The running time of this functions should be `size of ys * size of xs + size of zs * size of xs` which would make in Big-O, `O(Y) * O(X) + O(Z) * O(X)`.

Question is, are these running time analyses correct? If so, are the running time of those functions equal? Because from arithmetic `x * (y + z) = x * y + x * z`.

Results from ipython's `%timeit` function show that i seem to be wrong.

```
In [8]: ys1 = range(1, 500)

In [9]: zs1 = range(1, 1000)

In [11]: xs1 = range(1, 1000000)

In [12]: %timeit func1(xs1, ys1, zs1)
1 loop, best of 3: 15.7 s per loop

In [13]: %timeit func2(xs1, ys1, zs1)
1 loop, best of 3: 19.1 s per loop
```

Would like to understand what's wrong with my analyses. Thanks.

Comment: You're not doing any work inside the loop, so all you're timing is the loop overhead. Put something non-trivial in place of the `pass` statements. Then you'll be measuring something closer to the running-time of the algorithms.

Comment: Your analyses are fine. However, there is not a one-to-one correspondence between theory and practice.

Comment: calling `gc.collect()` before and after each use of timeit, seems to lead to more consistent results in my experience.

Comment: In fact, just replace `pass` with `steps += 1` (and add `steps=0` at the top and `return steps` at the bottom), then you can measure the actual number of "real" instructions executed, and validate that they're the same for both functions.

Comment: Damn it, how did you make `%timeit` work? I am getting a syntax error in the `%`.

Comment: @gsamaras that is a special feature of the ipython shell, in a standard python interpreter you would do `import timeit ; timeit.timeit("<statement>")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are measuring how long the for loops themselves take to execute, not the imaginary statement inside the loops.

When your loops are structured like this:

```
for x in xs:
    for y in ys:
        pass

    for z in zs:
        pass
```

Consider how many times each list is iterated over:

- `xs` is iterated over once from the outer loop
- `ys` is iterated over `X` times in the inner loop
- `zs` is iterated over `X` times in the inner loop

so the total iterations is `X * (1 + Y + Z)` which expands out to `X + XY + XZ`

Where as the number of times your `pass` statement executes is `X * (Y+Z)` or `XY + XZ` which is different from the number of total iterations.

When the loops are structured instead like this:

```
for y in ys:
    for x in xs:
        pass

for z in zs:
    for x in xs:
        pass
```

- `ys` iterated once from first outer loop
- `xs` iterated `Y` times in first inner loop
- `zs` iterated once from second outer loop
- `xs` iterated `Z` times in second inner loop

Meaning the total number of iterations is `Y*(1+X) + Z*(1 + X)` which expands out to `XY + XZ + Y + Z` Which is much different then the first equation.

however the number of `pass` statements that are executed are the same: `XY + XZ`

So basically: the number of actual statements executed are the same, however the number of iterations (getting the next element of a list) is generally greater for the second example, and since `pass` took less time then the for loop overhead the latter is what you were actually measuring.

Comment: Didn't know loops do have a overhead. Come across with this useful doc about loop performances; https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/.

Comment: Every operation (every byte code) takes time to execute, try running `import dis; dis.dis("for i in x:pass")` to see the exact bytecode used in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `O(x * (y + x))` instead of `O(X) * (O(Y) + O(Z))` (where x is length of X, y is length of Y, etc) to describe complexity of your first loop (O should "wrap" the whole expression)

Why?

Assume that f(x) is function that returns exact number of actions required to perform task with size x.

By definition f(x) = O(x) if there exist a, b so that a * O(x) + b = f(x) for all x (note that it also means that for all O(x), all a all b, all c and all d, `a * O(x) + b` = `c * O(x) + d`). To understand why this means that you need to have O wrapping the expression, consider the following loop:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        pass #  This is assumed to be exactly one action
```

Note that for this loop f(n) equals exactly to `n^2`

Let's say we decided that complexity of this loop as `O(n) * O(n)` rather than `O(n ^ 2)`. Then, `O(n)^2` = `(a*O(n)+b)^2` = `a^2 * O(n) + a * b * O(n) + b ^ 2`. You can notice that in expansions there appears `a ^ 2 * O(n)`. It makes it impossible to add or substract such constant that this expression would be always equal to f(n) because O(n) obviously changes depending on input size. Thus, this is wrong notation.

O(n^2) though would be just right, because for a=1 and b=1, `a*O(n)+b=f(n)` for all n.

Thus, we need to rewrite complexity for all your loops, keeping that in mind. For your first loop, the correct complexity is `O(x * (y + z))` = `O(x*y + x*z)`. For your second loop, the correct complexity is O(y*z + z*x).

So yes, the overall complexity for both loops is the same.

Comment: You seem to miss the part of the question about "why is `timeit` not taking the same amount of time for both"